# whats are the major disadvantages of using Membership API?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Whats are the major disadvantages of using Membership API? And when should i consider relying on using manual coding?

Comment: Use manual coding when the Membership API doesn't work for you scenario.

Comment: can u please explain with an example? please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEVER** write your own code for anything to do with security.  This includes authentication/membership.

Writing your own authentication system is deceptively easy: the basic functionally is simple to write and test.  However, the problem here is designing the process to be secure.  Because it's easy to do, it's also very easy to build something that only *seems* to work — it passes all your tests, allows those it's supposed to and does not allow those it isn't, and so you deploy your system.  Then along comes a hacker and finds that little flaw in your design.  A year later you finally find out you've been cracked.

The thing about the membership API is that it's extensible.  If there's not an out-of-the-box provider that does what you need you can extend one without having to start from scratch, so it would be pretty exception circumstances indeed that prevent you from using it.

This principle applies not only to ASP.Net, but also to any other platform where you might want to implement an authentication system.  Whatever platform you have, always lean as much as possible one the battle-tested security features provided to you.

Comment: Never unless you simply must. So i guess that means not never. @n10i

Comment: @code poet - The membership system is extensible. Can you describe to me anything you can't make it do?

Comment: no, joel, i can't describe anything that I haven't been able to make the membership system do. You may have misinterpreted my comment, which simply implies that saying **NEVER** is usually, um, never entirely accurate or helpful. You may have noticed in the few postings of guidance I have provided in the membership tag that I **ALWAYS** recommend leaning on intrinsic code whenever humanly possible and even when it almost isn't, but that there are definitely cases where custom implementation is the only route.

Comment: So i totally agree with the substance of your answer but completely disagree with advising someone looking for guidance to NEVER do anything. People, especially novices, are likely to take you literally